# Ubuntu 22.04 Not Regonizing GPU installed in ASUS TUF DASH F15

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I currently have Ubuntu 22.04 on my ASUS TUF DASH F15 Laptop, so far Ubuntu had been gong fine on it, but just recently for some reason ubuntu can no longer detect my graphics card in my system, it can see from `neofetch` that I am supposed to have a RTX 3060 Mobile Max-Q but NVIDIA-SMI says otherwise:

`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running`

And so does my ethereum miner I have setup on it, where the problem originally occurred, it worked for some time but after that it displayed this after some time:

`[19:07:28] ERROR - GPU 0 hung detected!`

`[19:07:28] ERROR - If this ERROR happened several times, or failed to detect some GPUs, please check your hardware.`

After seeing this I check to see if my drivers where installed and they sure were, even after uninstalling and installing them, after a reboot nothing would change. I checked to make sure this wasn't a physical issue by running by dual-boot of Windows 10, and I could run applications on my RTX 3060 just fine.

If someone has a solution within the next month that would be appreciated, but I am going to reset my Ubuntu install if the problem persists